# How much ventilation does a 30x30 detached garage need?

Tags: insulation, garage, ventilation

Let me start by saying we are in Houston. Very hot and humid during the summertime which lasts half the year.

I have a 30x30 detached garage that I would like to fully insulate and drywall. It has 8ft ceilings. I would also like to add more flooring in the attic to use for more storage.

We have two 12x12 vents on the east facing side of the roof. That's it.

We are installing a mini-split AC unit so we can workout during the summer as well. Solar panels on the N,S, and W facing side of the roof.

Comment: Full length vented soffit vents plus a full length ridge vent is the best.  Two vents on the same side is useless.  You want at least an intake on the low side and an output/exhaust on the the high opposite side.  Bigger is better.  The solar panels do help some with shading the roof.  Check the attic specs if the bottom chords can hold weight(for storage).  30 feet without support(beams under it) unlikely to hold much weight.